# Firebase Facebook and Google login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have integrated Google and Facebook login in my app using Firebase. I want to start the another activity automatically after the user Successfully logs-in using his Facebook or Google ID and also next time, when the user opens the app, he should automatically be redirected to the Homepage if he didn't logged out.

1. For Google, it is working fine, but for Facebook the Login button text is getting changed to "*logged in*", but it is not getting redirected to Homepage.
2. I also want to restrict a user to use only 1 login method at a time. I
   mean if he logs in from Facebook, he shouldn't be able to login from Google and vice versa.

Can anybody help? Below is my code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.aamir.myapplication.R;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class homeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // [START declare_auth]
    private static FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    // [END declare_auth]
    private static final String TAG = homeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // [START declare_auth_listener]
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    // [END declare_auth_listener]
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(homeActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Logging in");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
        mProgressDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
        // [START initialize_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // [END initialize_auth]
        // [START initialize_fblogin]
        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_btn);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        // [START auth_state_listener]
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(homeActivity.this, StaggeredViewActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]

                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };
// [END auth_state_listener]
        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // [END config_signin]

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(homeActivity.this, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        //Google Button Handle
        findViewById(R.id.google).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });



        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onSuccess:" + loginResult);
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onCancel");
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook:onError", error);
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Some Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        });
        // [END initialize_fblogin]
    }

    // [START on_start_add_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
    // [END on_start_add_listener]

    // [START on_stop_remove_listener]
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    // [END on_stop_remove_listener]


    // [START on_activity_result]
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Sign in Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }



        }
        else{
            // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        if(mGoogleApiClient!=null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

    }

    // [END on_activity_result]
    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        mProgressDialog.show();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    // [END auth_with_google]
    // [START auth_with_facebook]
    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        mProgressDialog.show();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }


    // [END auth_with_facebook]
    public static void signOut() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        //mAuth.signOut();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself what i did was i disabled and re-enabled the Email/Password feature in Firebase console and everything worked smoothly..

Answer (score 0):

Save user credentials in shared preference when they first-time register and then after check them whenever user start the application.